# Where can I find the Xposed Framework and installer for Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, xposed-framework

I am currently on **CyanogenMod 14.1**. I have been trying to find the **Xposed SDK 25** for **Android 7.1** but couldn't locate it. So I wanted to know:

If it is even out yet?

If yes then where can I find it?

Please help...

Comment: If you need it badly, go back to CM13.

Comment: @iBug so courteous of you to summon me like that...

Comment: Sorry for being rude for that time. I'm now moving on to another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updates / Corrections regarding

### Xposed Framework for Nougat / Oreo

Though, Xposed Framework for Nougat/Oreo still has not been released yet, here's an update/correction to the answers provided.

A) Rovo89, Original Creator & Developer for the Xposed Framework & Installer, continues his development for the Xposed Framework for Nougat/Oreo as of 13 July 2017.

B) Rovo89's last status update was made on 28 Jan 2017 here:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70773752&postcount=41

C) The following link is the official location (on XDA Developers) that Rovo89 uses for all status updates (please disregard the thread title as it also pertains to the Nougat/Oreo as well): 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811

D) Many individuals have been seeing my XDA Developers member name (also Ibuprophen) being used/referred to in a number of websites as either an additional or lone developer for the Xposed Framework for the Nougat/Oreo and wanted to set it straight that this is FALSE and has never been true (the PMs I received on XDA Developers are regarding this as a real pain in the rear-end). Rovo89 is the one and only Developer.

E) Any website that states otherwise is false and any files for the Xposed Framework for Nougat/Oreo are bogus ones that are either changed from the Marshmallow version to fake it in Nougat/Oreo or can just be dangerous. Get them from the source and not a third party.

Comment: So the other answer claiming it got a working Xposed for N is also a bogus? Glad I didn't actually try. +1

Comment: +1. Thanks for clarifying. Corrected my answer accordingly

Answer (score 4):

**Status Update**: Adding link to iBug's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188602/131553) , which gives details on availability of Xposed for Nougat .

Details below pertain to the state of things at the point of time of answering the question

---

Xposed for Nougat is not yet developed

- Rovo89, credited with Xposed framework development updated status [here in mid Nov 16](https://www.xda-developers.com/rovo89-updates-on-current-status-of-xposed-for-android-nougat/)
- <s>Another developer apparently is also working on it and is yet to be finalised, see [15th Dec update](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/xposed-android-nougat-7-0/)</s>

( See this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179398/131553) for reasons )

- You can follow [Google Plus Xposed](https://plus.google.com/communities/115950188312628751472) to monitor

Comment: Thanks for the this confirmation. I was just wondering that it has been two months now, it should have been out by now.

Comment: That's why added the last point to monitor progress. If the answer helps you, you can accept the answer by pressing the green tick arrow left of answer

Answer (score 2):

#### This answer is discontinued. Please move to [here](/a/188602/205764)

**Xposed for Oreo is unavailable by far because O is ... too new**

An **unofficial** build of Xposed Framework is [available](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-android-nougat-sdk-25-arm64-t3639221) from XDA. I have tested it with my OnePlus 5 and it worked perfectly.

The XDA newsfeed article is [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/flashable-xposed-framework-android-nougat/) and the thread is above.

> **Important Notice**
>   If you are using your stock ROM, make sure your `/data` partition **is decrypted**. If it's encrypted, you may have to format it. Be sure to back up your data carefully before proceeding. Also you should flash a "DM Verify and Forced Encryption Disabler" package.

Answer (score 0):

Xposed for Nougat is still under development. However, I found a working Xposed for Android Nougat but it only works on ARM devices. I tried it on Lineage OS but it didn't work so I used an old CM14.1 based ROM and it worked for me. You can try it yourself.

[Xposed Framework For Nougat](http://www.dexteroid.com/how-to/install-xposed-framework-on-android-nougat-7/)