# How to show date in status bar in Android 7?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, date-and-time

Back in Android 4/5, date was shown in the status bar along with time. However, I recently upgraded to Nougat/7 and now date is gone from the status bar and there doesn't seem to be any setting to re-add it.

Has this feature been removed? How do I get date to show in the top status bar, either in it's active or passive state?

Comment: It was?!?! I don't recall every having the date in the notification bar in any version of Android, at least since 2.1 which was my first Android version.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: @acejavelin, perhaps the author meant quick settings

Answer (score 2):

Change your display size to small (in settings --> display).

Comment: I don't know why Sam's answer is downvoted, it's actually correct. I had the same issue, when you first slide down and open the "pre" quick settings, the notifications and shortcuts to turning on/off some features (Wi-Fi for example) appear, and the time is shown on the top left. I knew that the date could also be shown then, and not only when you slide once more for the full quick settings. Well, if you change your display size to small, it does show. I think maybe it just doesn't fit in default display.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question as adequate as you may want it since I don't know if this option was completely removed or if it is present in a hidden state. Anyway, I can recommend you to install [GravityBox [N]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.nougat.gravitybox) Xposed module which allows to display time along with date in status bar.

If you don't know what [Xposed Framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) is, just Google "Xposed XDA" and read description. And, I also can't remember this feature available in older versions of Android at all, to be honest. Maybe it was added as part of manufacturer-provided Android modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After upgrading my Xperia Z5 from Android 6 to 7, the date is gone from the status bar. When pulled once on the bar the date used to be next to time, now it's gone. 
Potentially similar issue with alarm - the alarm time used to be shown next to time and used to be clickable to launch the alarm app. Now it only shows the alarm icon which is not clickable. I found a workaround for this issue by using the new Api that allows apps to add icons into the quick settings bar. So I used "quick settings" app to add the alarm app into the bar. 
I know there are apps that add the date into the status bar but I found none that would be nice and neat.

Comment: This isn't a forum. Your answer should contain an answer

Answer (score 0):

Now we have [Xposed Framework](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181918/205764) (As of Oct 10, 2017) and [GravityBox [N]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.nougat.gravitybox) (As of Oct 11, 2017) for Android N!

As a regular notice, flashing Xposed Framework may cause instability and unexpected behavior of your phone. Proceed at your own risk.

Get both of them, flash the Xp Framework via recovery, then install GB and reboot. Now open GB and navigate to *Status Bar -> Time Modification*. There you'll find the option named "Show date in status bar". Tap on it and it'll immediately take effect

Problem solved :)

---

P.S. I've never heard that Android has this function rawly supported. Is it a custom ROM?

Comment: An app I use that is very low memory and completely unobtrusive is Date In Status Bar. It simply puts the date and time in your preferred format on the status bar as a notification. Simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just pull down with 2 fingers and your date should be there.

Comment: In Android Nougat, Date displayed in `Notification Shade`.

Answer (score -2):

On Android 6:
Tap and hold the notification bar to see the date. Might still be valid for Nougat.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work on Nougat. Date is shown on the unlock screen, but not in the status bar.