# Charge & data mode when connecting phone to PC via USB (Nougat)

Tags: usb, charging, usb-connection-mode, data-transfer

When I connect my phone to my PC via USB. It automatically enters charge mode.

If I want to transfer files (which is almost always what I want to do when connecting my phone to my PC), I have to select charge & data mode --> transfer files.

Always doing this when connecting my phone to my PC is slightly laborious, and I was just wondering is there a way to connect my phone to my PC & cause to autmatically default to charge & data mode?

I used to have a Moto G Gen 1 (Kitkat), which did this by default, why can't this be the case on Nougat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour in Marshmallow upwards is to *charge* and other options have to be manually selected

Being an OS behaviour, you can't modify it without rooting device. If your device is rooted, you can install this Xposed module - [USB for Marshmallow](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-usb-marshmallow-1-0-t3272072)

> Set MTP or PTP as Default USB Connection on Marshmallow with this app.
>
> Once you connect the phone to the computer and select the USB option from the notification and selected option will be retained for every reconnect your phone to computer.
>
> For example if you select the USB file transfer option, This app will retain that file transfer option for every reconnect your phone to computer.

It's also [available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rayyan.black.fem.ind.runner) on Play Store as an Xposed app

If you are on Nougat, this option may not be possible till Xposed framework is released - see [Where can I find the Xposed Framework and installer for Nougat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167742/131553)

Answer (score 1):

If you device is rooted, you may use **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)** app to run a command as root to enable tethering *when USB is connected*.

The command can be found here: [**Is it possible to activate the “USB Tethering” Android setting from the command line?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98775/112458)