# Where can I find the Xposed Framework for Nougat and Oreo?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, xposed-framework, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo

I have a OnePlus 5 running stock Android 7.1.1. I'm planning to upgrade to 8.0 when it's available.

However I'm a huge Xposed fan and I use a lot of modules, so the availability of Xposed Framework is a great concern to me.

Comment: This post will be kept updated until a stable Xposed release for all Oreo versions, including possible further versions (8.2 or so), have been released.

Comment: Should this be a Community or FAQ posting?

Comment: Hrm... isn't that asking for off-site resources? And shouldn't it rather be integrated into our [xposed tag-wiki](/tags/xposed-framework/info)?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Last Updated: March 30, 2018](/posts/188602/revisions)

You can follow the [Xposed Framework](https://plus.google.com/communities/115950188312628751472) to monitor) community on Google+ so you can keep up to date with the news.

#### Update 3

[Xposed for Oreo 8.0/8.1 is available in beta](https://www.xda-developers.com/xposed-framework-for-android-oreo-beta/).

#### Update 2

Official Xposed v89 for up to SDK 25 (Android 7.1) is available [as of December 17, 2017](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=74880035#post74880035). A new version of Xposed Installer is available as well. *rovo89* says the Xposed for Oreo is ***almost complete***:

> 95% of the code are ported, basic functionality is working on Genymotion. The remaining 5% are obviously those parts of the code which are more difficult to port. I literally just upgraded my primary device to Android 8.1, so I can hopefully start some real testing soon.

#### Update 1

Official Xposed v88.1 for SDK 24 and 25 (Android 7.x) is available [as of October 10, 2017](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811).

---

#### Original Answer:

An **unofficial** build of Xposed Framework is [available](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-android-nougat-sdk-25-arm64-t3639221) from XDA. I have tested it with my OnePlus 5 and it worked almost perfectly, except for some small bugs (random reboot aroung 3:00 AM when I'm sleeping, requirement for `/data` decryption).

The XDA newsfeed article is [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/flashable-xposed-framework-android-nougat/) and the thread is above.

> **Important Notice**
>   If you are using your stock ROM, make sure your `/data` partition **is decrypted**. If it's encrypted, you may have to format it. Be sure to back up your data carefully before proceeding. Also you should flash a "DM Verify and Forced Encryption Disabler" package.

Comment: Should this be a Community or FAQ posting?